# Getting image data using the Imgur API and PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl, imgur

I'm quite new to php and I'm trying to use the imgur API (My code is based on several tutorials) What I'm trying to do is get an image from imgur display it on a web page. So I'm using this code

```
<?php  
  $client_id = '<ID>';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/rnXusiA');
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $json = json_decode($result, true);
?>
```

After converting `$result` to an associative array, I'm trying to access data

`$data = $json->data->link;`

But there's nothing in `$data` and I'm getting a `Trying to get property of non-object` error. I'm assuming imgur didn't return any data. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You convert `$result` to an associative array but still try to access data with `->`? If `$result` is an array, you access data by doing `$json['data']['link'];`.

Comment: use `print_r($result)` and see how the output is structured..

Answer (score 1):

I read more about `curl` and re-wrote the code.

```
<?php 
  $client_id = "<ID>";
  $c_url = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c_url, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($c_url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c_url, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/rnXusiA");
  curl_setopt($c_url, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
  $result=curl_exec($c_url);
  curl_close($c_url);
  $json_array = json_decode($result, true);
  var_dump($json_array);
?>
```

This wokred and `var_dump($json_array);` displayed the array content.

`$json_array['data']['link'];` gives the direct link to the image.

For an album, I changed the URL to `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/y1dZJ` and used a loop to get the image links

```
$image_array = $json_array["data"]["images"];

foreach ($image_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["link"];
}
```

I hope this helps anyone who's new to the imgur API.